# Como definir una funcion privada

Tags: c++

Alguien me podría indicar como debo definir una función privada en c++. Tengo esta definición de clase.

```
#ifndef AUTHOR_H_
#define AUTHOR_H_


#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Author {

private:
    string name;
    string email;
    char gender;


public:
    Author();
    Author(string name, string email, char gender);
    Author(const Author &rAuthor);
    Author & operator=(const Author &rAuthor);
   ~Author();

    string getName() const;
    string getEmail() const;
    char getGender() const;
    void setEmail(string email);
    void setEmail_2(string email);
    void print() const;
    bool checkGender(char gender) const;
};

#endif /* AUTHOR_H_ */
```

Y me gustaría que el método `checkGender`, fuera privado, pero si lo coloco en la parte private el el fichero `Author.h`, al definir las funciones no me aparece como perteneciente a la clase `Author`. La quiero definir como privada porque la va utilizar el contructor de mi clase, pero no la quiero hacer visible.

Fichero Author.cpp:

```
#include "Author.h"

Author::Author(){}

Author::Author(string name,string email, char gender){
    this->name=name;
    Author::setEmail_2(email);
    if(Author::checkGender(gender))
        this->gender=gender;
    else
        this->gender='';
}

bool Author::checkGender(char gender) const{
    if(gender == 'm' || gender == 'f' || gender=='u'){
       return true;
   }else{
       return false;
   }
}
```

Creo que esta toda la info, cualquier cosa me lo comentais. Gracias.

---

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si lo cambio a la zona private de la clase compuedes var no me aparece en la lista de metodos, disponibles,¿no debería aparecer en los métodos de la clase?

```
 class Author {

 private:
    string name;
    string email;
    char gender;
    bool checkGender(char gender) const;


public:
     Author();
     Author(string name, string email, char gender);
     Author(const Author &rAuthor);
     Author & operator=(const Author &rAuthor);
     ~Author();

     string getName() const;
     string getEmail() const;
     char getGender() const;
     void setEmail(string email);
     void setEmail_2(string email);
     void print() const;
     //bool checkGender(char gender) const;
```

};

Comment: Hace unos momentos leía el comentario de alguien en el stackoverflow en inglés que había hecho un "downvote" a una pregunta porque la pregunta había incluido una imagen. Comprendo perfectamente la razón de dicho downvote: si añades una imagen a una pregunta, es poco probable que dicha imagen siga siendo accesible en el futuro. Dado que no sólo preguntas para que te respondan, sino para que otros puedan beneficiarse de la pregunta, al poner una imagen estás reduciendo la utilidad que pudiese tener.

Answer (score 1):

> pero si lo coloco en la parte `private` el el fichero `Author.h`, al definir las funciones no me aparece como perteneciente a la clase `Author`

Eso es algo que deberías discutir con tu IDE. La forma de declarar funciones privadas es precisamente así, declarándolas en la parte `private`. En tu caso el programa debería funcionar correctamente y, si no compila, mira a ver qué estás configurando mal en tu IDE:

```
class Author {

 private:
    bool checkGender(char gender) const;
};

bool Author::checkGender(char gender) const
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Estoy desde mi celular por eso no puedo darte una respuesta precisa. Guíese de este ejemplo para adaptarlo a su necesidad, asuma lo siguiente, ya 
tienes tu `class`:

```
class Class1 {
    private:
    void metodo1();

    public:
    void metodo2();
};
```

**Implementa la función en tu `class`:**

```
void Class1::metodo1() { // <-- private
   // tu codigo
}

void Class1::metodo2() { // <-- public
   // tu codigo
   metodo1();              // <-- Llamando la función privada aquí.
}
```